# Self-Host SignalR with TLS 1.2

Tags: javascript, c#, cors, signalr

I wrote a self-hosted SignalR/OWIN/CORS windows service that resides on a user's local machine and receives SignalR calls from a remote website.  Everything worked just fine.  Then Starfleet Command decided that the remote site needed to be https://, so I made a self-signed cert and added the certificate binding similar to the instructions provided in this guide:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps

This got everything working again with SSL.  Now Big Brother is requiring that all API communication channels run with TLS 1.2, and they're blocking everything else, so now I'm running into TLS errors whenever the SignalR hub tries to connect.  I have no idea how to force my self-hosted SignalR service to use TLS 1.2.  Is such a thing possible, and if so, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: plus 1 for coming to the add of starfleet commode